# mysql: update 2 tables based on 1 input

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: `'matches'` and `'players'`.

In 'matches' I have individual goals scored and who by.

In 'players' I have individual players and goals scored.

How do I automatically update the player's total goals scored in the 'players' table when the players name gets a goal next to it in the 'matches' table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a third table `GOALS`.

```
create table GOALS(
   GOAL_ID INT,
   PLAYER_ID INT,
   MATCH_ID INT,
   GOAL_TIME DATE,
   ETC...
);
```

Then use this table to join to the `PLAYERS` and `MATCHES` tables.  This allows all `GOALS` to be stored in one location.  If you need to determine the amount of goals scored by a player or during a match you can execute a simple `count()` against the goals table.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `trigger` for the `matches` table. If a new record is added or deleted, the trigger would update the number of goals for the player.

Otherwise, you would make 2 queries: insert match record, update player record

Comment: wouldn't you have mutating table problems with trigger in the case you  select count from the same table? And if you don't select count but do like +1/-1 in trigger then you will fail with multi-user interactions

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
Here third table needed

create table GOAL(
   GID INT(PK),
   PID INT(FK of players),
   MID INT (FK of matches)
);

when This (GOAL) inserted then use a trigger used and update goal of players

CREATE TRIGGER ins_trig AFTER INSERT ON GOAL
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    -> UPDATE players SET goals scored(GIVE THE CONDITION);
    -> END;
```